# How to parse a string into discord data types?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am running into some issues because I would like to convert a value into a `discord.Member`.

The problem is I know I can do:

```
@commands.command
async def example(self, ctx, arg: discord.Member):
```

To cast `arg` to be a `Member`, but how would I do this directly from a string?

```
value = other_value: discord.Member
```

This returns a syntax error, how would I get to do this correctly?

Comment: What kind of value do you have that you want to get a `Member` from?  [Converters](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#converters) are only available in the function signature to indicate that some processing of inputs should be done before the command callback is called.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Sorry for nor being around, got it answered! And, yeah, it was around Converters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is called *function annotation*. Force casting the type of the parameter is not a feature of Python, instead, this is defined by discord.py. The arguments were converted prior to calling the function.

You **can’t** use local-variable annotation to achieve the same thing (actually you might be able to...but it’ll be extremely tedious), but you can achieve a similar effect by manually calling the `convert` method of discord.py’s `Converter`:

```
value = commands.MemberConverter().convert(ctx, other_value)
```

A list of available converters:

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/api.html#ext-commands-api-converters